# POST without id field in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is the model in my project:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

then I can POST with below JSON to create a new event

```
{
    title:"abc",
    id: "3b60a22c-d46e-46ca-b978-ec81a8b47fcc"
}
```

But If I post without id field

```
{
    title:"abc"
}
```

the request will return

```
{"id":["This field is required."]}
```

In this situation, I want the server auto-generate the id field, how to do?

Comment: Can you post your view en serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information provided in the question, I suppose your serializer is as follows:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id =  serializers.UUIDField()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

In this scenario **id** will be treated as a required field. So, in order to satisfy your requirement, change your serializer as:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
```